# Import error while importing a file in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-import, importerror

I have two files in the same location namely 'hello-depend.py' and 'second-package.py'

**hello-depend.py**

```
 class HelloDepend():

    def depend():

         print "depend"
```

**second-package.py**

```
from hello-depend import HelloDepend

 class SecondPackage():

    def second():

       print "second"

       h = HelloDepend()

       h.depend()


 if \__name__ == '\__main__':

    s = SecondPackage()

    s.second()
```

I need to create object for hello-depend.py from second-package.py. i tied with above method. But i am getting '**syntax error**' while importing 'hello-depend'.

**Error:**

File "second-package.py", line 1

```
import hello-depend

            ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So  i tried with below method.

import importlib

importlib.import_module('hello-depend')

but i am getting "**global name** 'HelloDepend' not defined'

Please help me in solving this.

**Note:** I need to do this without changing file name.

Comment: @MohitC I already tired that .. i am getting 'syntax error ' while importing

Comment: post the complete traceback

Comment: @MohitC . i have posted the error message

Comment: Remove `-` from module name and use `_` then try.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is `-` here. Python tries to treat it as minus symbol and `hello-depend` is not a valid identifier then.

Try to rename your file by replacing - with underscore (`_`)

Edit:
If you just cant change the file names, whatever the reason may be, then you can do

`execfile('hello-depend.py')`

Note that this does not import the file, it would get all the file globals into your own scope, and his highly unrecommended to solve this problem.

Comment: i need this functionality without changing the file name. I already mentioned that too.

Comment: Please read the PEP8 conevntion here. Python doesnt really allow packages names to be like that http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/